# How can I change this new MAC address?

Tags: mac-address, mac-spoofing

I have successfully changed my MAC address using `macchanger` from XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX to YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY. I executed `ip neigh` on Kali Linux and  got this output: `192.168.0.1 dev eth0 lladdr ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ STALE`. I am using a Modem Router. I want to know where this new MAC address is coming from and how I can change it.

Comment: What's the context? You might not have to change it.

Comment: Do you understand the `ip neigh` command that you ran?

Comment: @schroeder Do you understand the question?

Comment: @SandeepY The machine which I am setting up at the moment will be used for penetration testing. If I do not change this MAC, the attacker machine will be identified through the unchanged MAC.

Comment: @ShriDeviCharanSingh why talk about changing the MAC on an unrelated device when you want to change the MAC on a device somewhere else on your network? Your question boils down to "how can I find the device that belongs to this IP?" And that's not a security question ...

Comment: Unless you have known all along that the IP is from your router, in which case nothing in the question makes sense. If that is the case, then you need to read your router's manual.

Answer (score 1):

That IP is **another** device on the network and, based on its IP, I suspect it's the gateway. You can't change that MAC from your Kali box, you'll need to do it from the device broadcasting that MAC.

Comment: I am connected to that device. As I mentioned, it's a modem router. I want to change its MAC from terminal.

Comment: I'd imagine this is going to be device-specific instruction.

Answer (score 1):

By the question I can figure out :

1. You either want to change the MAC Address of the Modem Router Or
2. To find out weather it was changed? Or
3. To know weather the MAC change is possible?

Solution :

**Depends** on the Modem Router. Since there are many routers which allow the users to change the exposing MAC address(towards the ISP).

For example a typical TP-Link router config page :

[image]

A Cisco Router :

[image]

So bottom-line is, Yes you can change the Modem MAC Address if it supports. You just need to find the setting in the Modem Router Configuration.

Comment: I want to change this MAC from terminal.

Comment: If the Modem allows configuration via telnet, then try connecting to the modem via Telnet, and do the mac configuration. But the process would be device specific.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think u can do that MAC is practically the physical address

Comment: It is a physical address, but any operating system nowdays can use software settings to use another one.